# Finding the Median and Mode of $X \sim \operatorname{Expo}(\lambda)$

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

**Question** Let $X \sim \operatorname{Expo}(\lambda)$. Find the median and mode of $X \sim \operatorname{Expo}(\lambda)$.

My Solution:

[image: Solution to Question]

Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your final answer is correct but your working is not.

- In your working to find the median, there is this line
  $$e^{-\lambda m} = -\frac12.$$
  Exponential of any real number should be positive. You made a mistake involving the negative sign as you substitute the value in.
- In your working to find the mode, you claim that $\lambda=0$, but $\lambda$ is the parameter which should be positive. What you are interested is to find the value of $x$ that maximizes the probability density function. It need not satisfy $f'(x)=0$ as you claimed. It just have to be able to attain the maximum value which can occur at a boundary point.

Comment: $\exp(-0)=1$ is true, but you don't get to choose your $\lambda$, it is given to you. Your goal is to find maximum. One possible solution is to prove that the density function is a decreasing function. And oh, pick up [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553).

Comment: show that $f'(x)<0$.

Comment: first compute $f'(x)$?